# Is it possible to make a ban limit? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a Security bot for 4k server. Can make a ban limit is possible?

(What is **ban limit**?
- If someone bans members more than 2 (or 3 or 4 not problem) take member's role. Is this possible to do in **Discord.js**?

**I think** code starts with this event,

```
client.on('guildBanAdd', (guild, user) => {
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't make the code for you comeback after researching and facing an real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily achieve this by saving every Moderator in a collection and adding a counter for their Bans.

```
let banActions = new Discord.Collection;

client.on('guildBanAdd', (guild, user) => {
    //get the id of the user that banned someone
    const modId = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD'}).then(audit => audit.entries.first()).executor.id;
    let actEntry = banActions.get(modId);
    if(actEntry) {
        banActions.set(modId, actEntry + 1);
        if(actEntry + 1 > /* YOUR LIMIT HERE */) {
            //do stuff
        };
    } else {
        banActions.set(modId, 1);
    };
});
```

Comment: Although easy, this data will only be saved in the process's memory. If the Node.js process were to exit for any reason, the Collection would be lost.

Comment: That's correct, but I only wanted to give pointers in the right direction on how one might solve this problem. I'm not gonna write the entire system for the user, especially when they haven't made any attempt on their own.